# Can I visit the US after a visa denial under 212(a)(6)(C)(i)

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, visa-bans

In 2014, I got an F1 student visa. I completed my studies and got an H-1B visa approved in 2016. In 2017, I went to my country and, while there, went for my H-1B visa stamping. They rejected my visa under 212(a)(6)(C)(i): they found my work experience to be fake.

Now I am in Canada as a student. I would like to apply for USA visit visa. What are my chances of getting a visit visa in this situation? Can I apply directly for a visa or do I need to hire a lawyer for an appeal? How much do lawyers generally charge for this?

Comment: I am somewhat surprised you got a Canadian visa under these circumstances. If you were not honest about the previous rejection, you may find yourself on a plane out of Canada on short notice.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I was wondering the same myself. Most likely he did not tell the truth on his Canada student visa application.

Answer (score 6):

> Can you please help me about chances of getting visiting visa in this
>   situation.

You were bounced (had a visa application denied) for [212(a)(6)(C)(i) Material Misrepresentation/Fraud](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume8-PartJ.html) for self admittedly using fake work experience in your H1B petition. It is a **permanent bar** which can only be [removed via a waiver](https://www.uscis.gov/policymanual/HTML/PolicyManual-Volume9-PartG.html). Nobody here can help you. It requires the services of a competent reputable and typically expensive immigration attorney, not random guys from the internet which is what we are.

> Can I directly apply for visa or Do I need to hire a lawyer for an
>   appeal .

You can do either, your chances of success are almost nil. I would not recommend it unless you're rich and have lots of money to spare. For all intents and purposes barring some change in legislation, your only interaction with the USA for the rest of your life will be from afar.

> And how much generally lawyer charge for this case.

Opinion based. Different lawyers bill different amounts.

**CONCLUSION**

Do not waste the money trying to overturn a permanent ban for wilfull representation/fraud unless you desperately need to return to the USA (because for example you have a wife and children here) or maybe because your life will be meaningless if you do not return to the USA. Canada is a very beautiful country, enjoy it.

Comment: My tiny edit was to fix the parentheses

Comment: He wasn't bounced. He was refused a visa. That doesn't change much though.

Comment: @greatone We (in my country) use the same descriptor when one is denied a visa. It may be a malapropism